# Effective fast mobile ocr model

Tags: optical-character-recognition

I plan to develop OCR application which is mobile oriented and fast. (like 10~30 fps) The images that will be detected is not wild images. They are refined data such as cell phone capture images. In this situation what will be the most effective OCR model? I'm thinking yolo for text detection and bilstm for text recognition. However I don't have idea to make the model to end to end like [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.05611.pdf#page=15&zoom=100,180,238). Any idea or paper will be appreciated. Thanks for reading my question.